# CSS Transition not working perfectly

Tags: html, css

I've created a temporary page with two word message in  tag. The h1 has css3 infinite transition for shadow animation.

Shadow is visible fine for all side, but not has transition. Shadow change suddenly in every time duration.

If you see shadow carefully, then you will notice the shadow is not animation properly. Shadow is switching suddenly without animation from top to right, right to bottom, bottom to left and left to top again.

I'm just trying to move shadow in all side.

**See my fiddle here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/prL2j/

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    animation: message 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: message 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes message {
    25% {
        text-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    75% {
        text-shadow: -1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes message {
    25% {
        -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-text-shadow: -1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Coming Soon&hellip;</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure specifically what you meant, but note that if you have `-webkit-animation`, you also need to have `@-webkit-keyframes`